# MVC html.dropdownlist display selected value after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback, retain, html-select

I have an html.dropdownlist that is being populated in the Index action.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var maxyear = (from estiamte in dbBudget.Estimates
                       select estiamte.Year).Max();

        var years = (from estimate in dbBudget.Estimates
                     select new { estimate.Year }).Distinct().ToList();

        ViewData["Years"] = new SelectList(years.OrderByDescending(o => o.Year), "Year", "Year");

        var vu_Estimates = dbBudget.vu_Estimates.OrderByDescending(o => o.Expense).ThenBy(o => o.CategoryGroupSortOrder).ThenBy(o => o.SortOrder).Where(o => o.Year == maxyear).ToList();

        return View(vu_Estimates);
    }
```

I'm defining the html.dropdownlist so that changing the value will trigger a postback:

```
<div>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("Years", (SelectList)ViewData["Years"], new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%> | <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New Year of Estimates", "CreateEstimates", "Estimate") %>
    <%} %>
</div>
```

I'm capturing the postback and filtering the displayed table.  I'm trying to have the dropdown list display the chosen value, but that is not working.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        var years = (from estimate in dbBudget.Estimates
                     select new { estimate.Year }).Distinct().ToList();

        int year = Convert.ToInt32(formCollection["Years"]);

        ViewData["Years"] = new SelectList(years.OrderByDescending(o => o.Year), "Year", "Year", year);

        var vu_Estimates = dbBudget.vu_Estimates.OrderByDescending(o => o.Expense).ThenBy(o => o.CategoryGroupSortOrder).ThenBy(o => o.SortOrder).Where(o => o.Year == year).ToList();

        return View(vu_Estimates);
    }
```

What do I need to do to have the dropdown list display the selected value after postback instead of the first value in the list?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to name the `Html.DropdownList` to something other than `Years`, e.g. `ddlYears`.